# Как сделать коллизию двух кубов, чтобы если куб при столкновении с другим кубом останавливался в том же месте и не двигался вперед?

Tags: pygame

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]    [image: вот так выглядит моя игра]Вот код игры.

```
import random
from os import path

import pygame

pygame.init()

width, height = 800, 600  # разрешение
TILE = 40  # размер клетки[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
FPS = 10  # количество кадров в секунду
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

display = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))  # дисплей
title = pygame.display.set_caption("игра")  # заголовок
pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()  # нажатия мыши
count_select = 0  # количество выбранных кубиков

# работа с изображениями
img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'images')  # подключение папки с изображениями
background = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, 'bg_fon.jpg')).convert()  # загрузка изображения на фон
background_rect = background.get_rect()  # установка прямоугольника на фон~

# работа с музыкой
snd_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'sounds')  # подключение папки с музыкой
pygame.mixer.music.load(path.join(snd_dir, 'tgfcoder-FrozenJam-SeamlessLoop.mp3'))  # загрузка музыки
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.4)  # установка громкости музыки


class Cube:
    x, y = 0, 0
    red, green, blue = 0, 0, 0
    select = 0

    def draw(self):  # отрисовка
        pygame.draw.rect(display, (self.red, self.green, self.blue), (self.x, self.y, TILE, TILE))

    def move(self):  # движение
        global Cube_arr
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  # нажатия клавиатуры
        if (self.y <= height - TILE and self.y >= 0 and self.x <= width - TILE and self.x >= 0):
            if self.select == 1:
                if keys[pygame.K_d] and self.x != width - TILE:
                    self.x += TILE
                if keys[pygame.K_a] and self.x != 0:
                    self.x -= TILE
                if keys[pygame.K_w] and self.y != 0:
                    self.y -= TILE
                if keys[pygame.K_s] and self.y != height - TILE:
                    self.y += TILE

    def __init__(self):  # конструктор
        self.red = random.randint(50, 255)
        self.green = random.randint(50, 255)
        self.blue = random.randint(50, 255)
        self.x = random.randint(0, (width - 1) // TILE) * TILE
        self.y = random.randint(0, (height - 1) // TILE) * TILE
        print("куб создан. его координаты - " + "(" + str(self.x) + "," + str(self.y) + ")")


Cube_arr = []


def run_game():  # главная функция (main)
    cubes_n = 4
    for i in range(cubes_n):  # массив кубов
        cube = Cube()
        Cube_arr.append(cube) #
    print("всего кубов:", cubes_n)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)  # запуск музыки
    while (True):  # главный игровой цикл

        global count_select
        mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()  # позиция мыши
        drawGridAndBG()
        for cube in Cube_arr:
            cube.draw()
        for cube in Cube_arr:
            cube.move()
            if(cube.collide()):
                print("collide")

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    for cube in Cube_arr:
                        if (count_select == 0):
                            if mousex >= cube.x and mousex <= cube.x + TILE and mousey >= cube.y and mousey <= cube.y + TILE:
                                cube.select = 1
                                count_select += 1
                                print("этот куб выбран для управления\n")
                if event.button == 3:
                    for cube in Cube_arr:
                        if (cube.select == 1):
                            if mousex >= cube.x and mousex <= cube.x + TILE and mousey >= cube.y and mousey <= cube.y + TILE:
                                cube.select = 0
                                count_select = 0
                                print("этот куб больше не выбран\n")
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)


def drawGridAndBG():  # рисование сетки и фона
    display.blit(background, background_rect)  # установка изображения на фон
    for i in range(0, width + 1, TILE):  # рисование сетки
        pygame.draw.line(display, pygame.Color("dimgray"), (i, 0), (i, height), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(display, pygame.Color("dimgray"), (0, i), (width, i), 1)


run_game()
```

Comment: Исправьте форматирование и добавьте картинку

Comment: а как картинку добавить?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать функцию `pygame.sprite.collide_rect()` для обнаружения столкновений.

Первые два аргумента - сами объекты, а третий (по умолчанию False) аргумент показывает, уничтожатся ли **оба** спрайта при коллизии.

Это удобнее чем высчитывать все самостоятельно, но оно не будет отслеживать столкновения попиксельно (только по прямоугольным хитбоксам). Но у вас кубы квадратные, поэтому вам должно хватить.

Таким образом вы можете написать:

```
if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(*cube1*, *cube2*):
    # Обработка
```

Если хотите могу дать официальную документацию pygame на английском: https://www.pygame.org/docs/